# Show tables and give option to delete

Tags: php, mysql

I would like everyone to see the entries of my table and that there is a possibility to remove a row, 
[image]

As you can see, I want that the user can click on delete and that it removes from database:)

This is what I've got so far:

```
function editRooster() {
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {   
        if(isset($_POST['delete_id'])) {
        $delete_id = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['delete_id']);
        mysql_query("DELETE FROM event WHERE `id`=".$delete_id);
        header('Location: dashboard.php');
        }
    }
    else {

    echo '<h1><a href="dashboard.php">Het terras</a> &rsaquo; <a href="dashboard.php?app=mysql">Roosters</a> &rsaquo; <a href="dashboard.php?app=mysql&action=editrooster">Wijzigen</a></h1>';
        $connection = mysqlConnect();

 // Find out how many items are in the table
    $total = $connection->query('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM intranet_users')->fetchColumn();

    // How many items to list per page
    $limit = 20;

    // How many pages will there be
    $pages = ceil($total / $limit);

    // What page are we currently on?
    $page = min($pages, filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'page', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, array(
        'options' => array(
            'default'   => 1,
            'min_range' => 1,
        ),
    )));

    // Calculate the offset for the query
    $offset = ($page - 1)  * $limit;

    // Some information to display to the user
    $start = $offset + 1;
    $end = min(($offset + $limit), $total);

    // The "back" link
    $prevlink = ($page > 1) ? '<a href="?app=users&page=1" title="Eerste pagina">&laquo;</a> <a href="?app=users&page=' . ($page - 1) . '" title="Vorige pagina">&lsaquo;</a>' : '<span class="disabled">&laquo;</span> <span class="disabled">&lsaquo;</span>';

    // The "forward" link
    $nextlink = ($page < $pages) ? '<a href="?app=users&page=' . ($page + 1) . '" title="Volgende pagina">&rsaquo;</a> <a href="?app=users&page=' . $pages . '" title="Laaste pagina">&raquo;</a>' : '<span class="disabled">&rsaquo;</span> <span class="disabled">&raquo;</span>';

    // Prepare the paged query
    $stmt = $connection->prepare('SELECT * FROM event ORDER BY id LIMIT :limit OFFSET :offset');

    // Bind the query params
    $stmt->bindParam(':limit', $limit, PDO:: PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->bindParam(':offset', $offset, PDO:: PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->execute();

    // Do we have any results?
    if ($stmt->rowCount() > 0) {
        // Define how we want to fetch the results
        $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $iterator = new IteratorIterator($stmt);

        // Display the results
        echo '<table><thead><td>ID:</td><td>Voornaam:</td><td>Datum</td><td>Vanaf</td><td>Tot</td><td>Omschrijving</td><td>Wijzig</td><td>Verwijder</td></thead>';
        foreach ($iterator as $row) {
            echo '<tr><td>';
            echo $row['id'];
            echo '<td>';
            echo $row['firstname'];
            echo '</td><td>';
            echo (new \DateTime($row['date']))->format('d-m-Y');
            echo '</td><td>';
            echo $row['begintijd'];
            echo '</td><td>';

        echo $row['eindtijd'];
        echo '</td><td>';
        echo $row['omschrijving'];
        echo '</td><td>';
        echo '<input type="submit" value="Edit">';
        echo '</td><td>';
        echo '<form method="post">';
        echo '<input type="hidden" name="delete_id" value="'.$row['id'].'" />';
        echo '<input type="submit" value="Delete">';
        echo '</form>'; 

    }
    echo '</table>';
}
} 
}
```

Sorry that the function is so long, but I've got no idea what is wrong, so I have to post the entire function. Excuse me for the long code:)

Comment: Your button needs to have the name "submit" since that's the $_POST variable that you're looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `$connection` is a PDO object.

Try calling your delete query this way:

```
$query = "DELETE FROM event WHERE id=?";
$stmt = $connection->prepare($query);
$stmt->bindParam(1, $delete_id);
$stmt->execute();
```

You also don't need to escape the value of `$delete_id` with `mysql_real_escape_string()` since it's a prepared statement.

(Answer written after a debugging discussion in the PHP chatroom).

Answer (score 0):

change

```
echo '<input type="submit" value="Delete">';
```

to

```
echo '<input type="submit" name = "submit" value="Delete">';
```

Comment: he sends me to  header('Location: dashboard.php'); however, it doesn't remove anything from database